# MongoDB ISODate value with 0 milliseconds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

In a MongoDB collection, I am storing some documents that has 2 properties startTime and endTime both of which are of type ISODate.

The code is written in javascript (node.js) and Mongoose to interact with MongoDB.

The mongoose models are something like the following:

```
startTime: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
},
endTime: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
},
```

In my code, I am explicitly setting the seconds and milliseconds to 0 before insertion to the database. However the dates inserted have some extra bits that's I'm assuming to be milliseconds (I might be mistaken)

this is an extract from my code which sets the seconds and milliseconds to 0

```
let startTimeMoment = moment.utc(startTime);
startTimeMoment.seconds(0);
startTimeMoment.milliseconds(0);

let endTimeMoment = moment.utc(endTime);
endTimeMoment.seconds(0);
endTimeMoment.milliseconds(0);
```

Below is a screenshot from the a document in the database collection

[image]

The reason this is problematic is because I am running some queries that takes into consideration the startTime and endTime and because of these milliseconds the queries are returning empty results.

What am I missing?

Comment: What you're showing should work. Can you provide the minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It turns the code was behaving as expected.

Even though I was setting the seconds and milliseconds to 0, I was saving the values before the update the the database (facepalm)